# Add a field value outside form in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

Whenever I have to add a value to the instance of a form obtained from the context or from the URL I do it in the following way, using form.instance.

```
class PreguntaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pregunta
        fields = ('etiqueta', 'grupo', 'tipo_pregunta', 'opciones', 'mostrar_tabla', 'activo')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cuestionario = kwargs.pop('cuestionario', False)
        super(PreguntaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['grupo'].queryset = Grupo.objects.filter(cuestionario=cuestionario)

class PreguntaNueva(InfoPregunta, CreateView):
     form_class = PreguntaForm
     encabezado = 'Nueva Pregunta'
     model = Pregunta

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(PreguntaNueva, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['cuestionario'] = self.dame_cuestionario()
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.cuestionario = self.dame_cuestionario()
        return super(PreguntaNueva, self).form_valid(form)
```

The problem that arises now is that I want to perform a check CreateView and EditView. To DRY, I want to do it in the clean method of the model, but the value that I assign to form.instance.cuestionario, is not available within the clean method. How could I do it? This value must not be edited by the user in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, you pass it in via `get_form_kwargs`; you just need to assign it to an instance variable in the form's `__init__`.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.cuestionario = kwargs.pop('cuestionario', False)
    super(PreguntaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['grupo'].queryset = Grupo.objects.filter(cuestionario=self.cuestionario)

def clean(self):
    # do something with self.cuestionario
```

Comment: I think your solution is valid with form's clean method. But I'm trying to do it in the model's clean method.